# Acting upon closing with subclassed NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I got a custom `NSView` which does some drawing and I use a struct to keep the properties for my animated ball, in that struct I got a `CGColorRef` as ARC forbids me to have obj-c object inside a struct.

Now the question is how will I release my `CGColorCreateGenericWithRed` function when I close my application, and the tricky part is, I want the `NSView` subclass to be "self contained" with that I mean I don't want to refer to the subclass from my `AppDelegate` class.

I've looked through the Apple Developer Docs, but it seems that `NSView` do not react upon its release and/or the disposal of its parent window, and with that in mind I assume I will have a leaking `CGColorRef`, ofcourse I will, again, assume that it will be collected when the application is closed and make no harm in the end of the day.

**So to repeat myself, I want to know how I can release my `CGColorRef` from the subclassed `NSView` without having to expose the struct outside the `NSView` subclass.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Subclassed NSView you will have to add 1 of these two methods:

ARC:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   //Release CGColorRef
}
```

Non-ARC:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   //Release CGColorRef
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can release it the same was as in your pre-ARC days - add a `dealloc` method. Under ARC you don't include `[super dealloc]` but otherwise it is the same.

From [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed you cannot) release instance variables, but you may need to invoke [systemClassInstance setDelegate:nil] on system classes and other code that isn’t compiled using ARC.
>
> Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc] (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is automated and enforced by the compiler.
>
> You can still use CFRetain, CFRelease, and other related functions with Core Foundation-style objects (see “Managing Toll-Free Bridging”).